# How to find where content is taken for a Template Voila element in Typo3

Tags: typo3

I have to mantain a few websites made in Typo3 and generally it is not overcomplicated, but when it has Template Voila it get's crazy.

So now I am stuck trying to change some sidebar and I don't know where the content is taken.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMpuL.png

I have the website shown in the previous image, and I need to find out where the content that is shown on the field_sidebar is taken from. If I click on Re-Map and then edit I am sent to a screen where in Element Preset specifies Typoscript Object Path. But there is no other clue as to where the content is taken from.

The Template Setup has only 40 lines and none of them mention any sidebar, so my guess is that everything is done within Template Voila.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check in the template object browser if the TypoScript path given there is actually set? If so, you can use the template analyzer to find out where it is set. Maybe in the static TS of a template extension or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in a comment the TypoScriptObjectPath defines where the content comes from. In the Backend there is a module called template and if you click on it you have a dropdown at the top of the page where you can select TypoScriptObjectBrowser.

Now you have to find your TypoScriptObject in the TypoScriptObjectBrowser. Switch the dropdown to "setup" if it shows "constants" then use the search with the last part of your TypoScriptObject path. E.g. if it says

```
path.to.my.typoscriptObject
```

in TemplaVoila. Type typoscriptObject into the search field. All occurences of this TypoScript Object are now highlighted. The Typoscript you find is responsible for rendering any content whithin your sidebar. Adjust it to your needs.